# MatSelect dropdown doesn't work if originally loaded as Disabled, but dynamically updated to not be disabled

Tags: .net, blazor, matblazor

I have a blazor app where I am using MatBlazor's MatSelect component.

I have a Disabled State based on a couple of booleans like so:

```
<MatSelect TValue="Guid" 
           @bind-Value="@SomeViewModel.Customer"
           Disabled="@(!IsAdmin || HasProducts)">
    <MatOption Value="new Guid()" Disabled="true">Please select</MatOption>
    @foreach(var customer in AvailableCustomers)
    {
        <MatOption Value="customer.Id">@customer.Name</MatOption>
    }
</MatSelect>
```

So basically the customer field is editable for admin users and only if the customer has no products (This is a sample scenario loosely based on what Im building). When the page is loaded and Disabled is false, I can click the MatSelect box and get my dropdown options no problem, but if its loaded and Disabled is true, when removing the products, thus making the Disabled state false, the field becomes clickable again but my dropdown list doesn't show.

Now just to confirm, the AvailableCustomers List IS populated and I can see the html in the page, just that it isn't becoming visible.

***What I have already tried***
I have a method to remove products from the `SomeViewModel` which I also tried adding `StateHasChanged()` and this still didn't work.

```
public void RemoveProduct(
    ProductListViewModel productListViewModel)
{
    SomeViewModel.Products.Remove(productListViewModel);

    // Notify EditContext of the change
    FormEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(() => SomeViewModel.Product));

    CheckForDuplicateProducts();

    // Didnt work
    // StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: Where is `HasProducts` being set?

Comment: I managed to fix the issue myself here: https://github.com/liamkavfc/MatBlazor